# Check if row exist

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

The following PL/SQL code behaves differently if the WHERE looks like this:

```
WHERE USERNAME = 'aaaaaa'
```

and differently if looks like this:

```
WHERE USERNAME = userName
```

Why is the result not the same if `userName := 'aaaaaa'`? What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you!

```
declare
  isFound  NUMBER;
  userName VARCHAR2(30);
begin
  isFound  := 0;
  userName := 'aaaaaa';

  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO isFound
    FROM MyTable
   WHERE USERNAME = 'aaaaaa' -- userName
     AND ROWNUM = 1;

  IF isFound > 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Found');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Not found');
  END IF;

end;
```

Comment: you cannot wrrite rownum=1 rather should use rownum<2

Comment: @Harshit - [yes you can](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da67e/1); `1` is the only value you *can* use `=` with. `rownum = 2` will never find any rows because it isn't true for the first row found; but `rownum = 1` *is* true for the first row found (and not for the second), so that's OK. However, using `< 2` might make code more consistent...

Comment: +1 for using plsqldeveloper but -1 for not using the easy breezy debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this version:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO isFound
    FROM MyTable
   WHERE USERNAME = userName
     AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

... the table's `USERNAME` column is being compared with itself, so it will always match. You are not comparing it with the local variable. If you want to do that, you'll need to give the variable a different name to the column:

```
declare
  isFound  NUMBER;
  localUserName VARCHAR2(30);
begin
  isFound  := 0;
  userName := 'aaaaaa';

  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO isFound
    FROM MyTable
   WHERE USERNAME = localUserName
     AND ROWNUM = 1;

  IF isFound > 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Found');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Not found');
  END IF;

end;
```

Or as David Aldridge suggests, use a label to distinguish the local variable from the table column:

```
<<local>>
declare
  isFound  NUMBER;
  userName MyTable.USERNAME%TYPE;
begin
  isFound  := 0;
  userName := 'aaaaaa';

  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO isFound
    FROM MyTable
   WHERE USERNAME = local.userName
     AND ROWNUM = 1;
...
```

You can use that approach with named blocks too; if this was inside a function you could refer to a local variable as `function_name.variable_name`. Since this is an anonymous block the label plays the same role as `function_name` would, essentially.

The documentation has [a section about name resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/nameresolution.htm).

Comment: +1, and also consider naming the block <<MY_NAME>> and prefixing the variable with it in the SQL as "WHERE USERNAME = MY_NAME.USERNAME" instead ;)

Comment: @DavidAldridge - that's an option I really need to consider more often, particularly in named blocks, instead of using a prefix for the local name (I know that's one of your bugbears *8-).

Comment: To be really annoyingly nitpicky there's no need to initalise the `isFound` variable as count is an aggregate function and so 1 or 0 will always be returned... the microsecond you save will be useless in most systems! </all part of my save the computrons campgaign>

Answer (score 2):

You can use label.

```
<<the_code>>
declare
  isFound  NUMBER;
  userName VARCHAR2(30);
begin
  isFound  := 0;
  userName := 'aaaaaa';

  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO isFound
    FROM MyTable
   WHERE USERNAME = the_code.userName
     AND ROWNUM = 1;

  IF isFound > 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Found');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Not found');
  END IF;

end;
```