# oracle cursor is not updating data

Tags: oracle, cursor

I made an example to better explain the situation:

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE AA
(
    ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    REFERENCE NVARCHAR2(100) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE BB
(
    ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    IDA NUMBER NOT NULL,
    REFERENCE NVARCHAR2(100) NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (IDA) REFERENCES AA(ID)
)
```

and some records

```
INSERT INTO AA VALUES(1, NULL)
INSERT INTO AA VALUES(2, NULL)
INSERT INTO AA VALUES(3, NULL)
INSERT INTO AA VALUES(4, NULL)
INSERT INTO AA VALUES(5, NULL)

INSERT INTO BB VALUES(6, 1, 'AAA')
INSERT INTO BB VALUES(7, 2, 'BBB')
INSERT INTO BB VALUES(8, 3, 'CCC')
```

I have to set `REFERENCE` field of `AA` with the value that's in `BB` by `IDA`.

So I decided to use a cursor

```
DECLARE 
    idA NUMBER;
    reference NVARCHAR2(100);

    CURSOR ref_cursor
    IS
        SELECT IDA, REFERENCE FROM BB;
BEGIN

    OPEN ref_cursor;

    LOOP
        FETCH ref_cursor into idA, reference;
        EXIT WHEN ref_cursor%NOTFOUND;

        UPDATE AA 
        SET REFERENCE = reference 
        WHERE ID = idA;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('reference of movement ' || idA || ' updated with ' || reference);

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE ref_cursor;
END;
```

By executing it, I get an output

```
reference of movement 1 updated with AAA
reference of movement 2 updated with BBB
reference of movement 3 updated with CCC
```

That's exactly what I want, but when I check the data by star-selecting the table I found the `REFERENCE` column still `NULL`.

So I found this other cursor

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR ref_cursor
    IS 
       SELECT IDA, REFERENCE FROM BB;

BEGIN
    FOR ref_c IN ref_cursor
    LOOP
         UPDATE AA SET REFERENCE = ref_c.REFERENCE WHERE ID = ref_c.IDA;            
    END LOOP;
END;
```

This one is actually doing the update. Why are these 2 cursors different?

Comment: Can you change your local variable reference to a different name  (in your first cursor example) and try again ?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18875833/266304), not sure if it's close enough to be a duplicate, but it's the same name resolution issue. [As is this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25574647/266304).

Comment: There is no commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a SQL statement is processed inside a PL/SQL block, the SQL name resolution takes priority so, table fields have precedence over variables with the same name. To solve this issue you have two ways:

- change the variable name.
- add a prefix to the variable name as you already did in your second query.

Answer (score 0):

In the first cursor you wrote

```
UPDATE AA 
        SET REFERENCE = reference 
        WHERE ID = idA;
```

I think you should rename the variable to different name